# informatica mapping examples

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica-powercenter

I want to develop a generic mapping for handling database errors in PowerCenter.
Can anyone give me any examples of such mappings?

Also can you suggest me some resources for PowerCenter samples mappings?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to common informatica errors and error handling(includes samples):

http://www.informaticans.com/blog/179/error-handling/

Answer (score 1):

Usually a session encounters database errors when writing a row to the target. You have the option to either:

1. Stop the session first error
2. continue the session after rejecting the row

The error itself is recorded in the session log and the row written in the reject file.

If you choose to stop the session on first error then you use the following mapping example to capture database row errors into a flat file or database:

https://community.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_logging_error_rows